# How to play free-for-all with more than 1 CPU player in SSBU?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

Just got SSBU, and am eager to get into the chaos (i.e. more than 2 players). However, so far I only see vs battles and other odd specializations - is this something that needs to be unlocked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add up to 8 player slots by clicking the "Add Members" button on the bottom-right of the character select screen.

[image: "Add Members" button]

Once added, you can change a player into a CPU by clicking the bottom box.

[image: Changing players into CPU]

Comment: Thanks - I realize now that part of my problem is my usual issues with noticing visual cues, and part of it is that the edge of the rendered view is a bit cut off on my television. But that's another question!

Comment: @bbarker (Almost?) all modern TVs have an option to fit the whole image into the screen. It's usually found near the aspect ratio options.

Comment: @inakilbss Thanks for the pro tip, can confirm it works. I am grateful, but now feel technologically inept, despite having a job in tech.

Comment: I know your feel, as I often get berated for loving computers and not being able to navigate some websites.